# ¿Cómo trasladar código de Python a Java?

Tags: java, python

Necesito trasladar este código a java. Está en python:

```
    def totalPaginas(libros):
     if len(libros) == 1:
      return libros[0]
     else:
     return libros[0] + totalPaginas(libros[1:])
    a = [50, 100, 150]
    resultado = totalPaginas(a)
    print("la suma de todas las paginas de los libros es igual a %i "  % resultado)
```

Mi código en java:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

int a[] =  {50, 100 , 150};
int resultado = totalPaginas(a); 
System.out.println("el total de paginas es: " +resultado);

public static int totalPaginas(int libro){ int res;

   if(libro==1){
       return 0;
       } else{
           return libro (0) + totalPaginas(libro(1);
         }
```

Comment: Que te tiene trabado? Por que no lo haces? Ten en cuenta que las preguntas sin una demostracion de que su autor es parte de la busqueda de la respuesta no suelen ser bien recibidas y terminan cerradas y/o votadas negativamente.

Comment: no soy muy experto en java el cual no me ha dejado avanzar ya que el codigo lo desarrolle en phyton pero necesito hacerlo en java :(

Comment: **Python***. Pulsa en [edit] y muestra lo que has intentado para traducir, y el problema _específico_ que has tenido. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Demuestra que realmente has hecho el esfuerzo por tu parte para resolver tu problema.

Comment: Entonces tal vez requieras primero adquirir algunos conocimientos de java. Luego de eso, piensa cuales son las equivalencias entre Python y Java.

Comment: No traducimos codigo... Y parte de aprender java, es entender tu codigo y poder buscar como hacer lo mismo en java. Asi como esta, suena a que pides que hagan el ejercicio por vos...

Comment: lo estoy haciendo pero no me dapublic static void main(String[] args){
    
      int a[] =  {30 ,40 ,55, 60 ,70};
      int resultado = totalPaginas(a); 
      System.out.println("el total de paginas es: " +resultado);
    
    public static int totalPaginas(int libro){
        int res;
        
        if(libro==1){
            return 0;
            } else{
                return libro (0) + totalPaginas(libro(1);
            
        }

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega la versión Java.

Comment: ya lo agrege se puede visualizar?

Comment: No agregaste la versión de Java. Y por cierto, no olvides mencionar _cuál es el problema en cuestión_. "No me sale", "no se me da", "da error" o similares no son argumentos suficientes: expláyate. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu preguntar.

Comment: eso que agregasta va por el camino correcto.. obviamente no compila.. que recibe en python la funcion totalPaginas y que pusiste que recibe la de java?

Comment: @padaleiana no entendí por qué quitarle el formato de pregunta al título. Todo bien, sólo que no entendí.

Comment: @Alfabravo era eso o agregarle los signos de interrogación nada más; puedo modificarlo de nuevo, sin problema :)

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que para reemplazar el operador slice :1 en java es necesario de un parámetro adicional en el método el cual represente el ultimo indice en el array el cual disminuya hasta llegar al caso base

```
public static int totalPaginas(int[]a,int indiceFinal){
 int n=indiceFinal;
   if(n==0) //caso base
    return a[n];
    else 
      return a[n] + totalPaginas(a,n-1);
     }

int a[] =  {50, 100 , 150};
int resultado = totalPaginas(a,a.length-1); 

System.out.println("el total de paginas es: " +resultado);
```

Comment: muchas gracias si tenia esa idea , anexe un poco mas de codigo  y me funciono te agradezco

Comment: @Sebbas04 si te sirvió la respuesta adjunta podes validarla dándole al icono de ✓,saludos